# Heroku or digital ocean deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment, digital-ocean

Maybe someone experienced can give me a hand with understanding what's a better solution for me.

I'm currently working on a Telegram Bot which has a web interface consisting of frontend part as Vue framework app and the backend part as Express app.

I found out that buying Hobby dyno on Heroku you can deploy only one app there what doesn't look good to me because I would need to buy three dynos for each app since Bot is an app itself and mixing it with express would be a mess.

I'm thinking what if I buy space on Digital Ocean. Can it solve my problem with at least these three-part app?

I've never had such experience before so your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you to go for a VPS (e.g. digital ocean). It's closer to reality, you learn more and it is more versatile. Theoretically it is possible to bundle multiple application as a single app on Heroku but that will require a lot of work. But troubleshooting and getting it to work on Heroku is harder. You have less control over the build process and you cannot make tiny adjustments easily. You have to build completely from scratch.   
Frontend that are static websites can be served easily e.g. on GitHub pages. There are a lot of similar services which are free. Backend stuff are not free.

Comment: @TinNguyen thanks a lot for your response! I thought about mixing Bot with backend but it would be a mess to sustain and develop. That’s why I was curious if I can use one drop for a few apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Heroku you need to setup a Web Dyno for each of your application which requires HTTP connectivity, however you can create each application in the Free Tier at no-cost.
Your 3 components architecture can run for free (apps sleep after 30 min of inactivity).

Do you have Docker images? Then deploy them in the [Heroku Container Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). You can develop/deploy/test without cost then (when production-ready) decide to move to other hosting or purchase the  Hobby tier ($7 per Dyno).

Heroku Developer experience is top: Docker registry or GitHub integration, logs viewer, secrets via env variables. You focus on development and let Heroku worry about the platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’m currently using Heroku Free Tiers for one of them but trying to deploy my backend I keep getting the same error with memory leaks with V8. I never faced that before and locally it runs well and fast on my Windows machine but on Heroku that error doesn’t let me move on with deployment. That’s the reason I started to think on a paid plan because I don’t know how to overcome that error and support doesn’t help free dynos. Maybe you can help me out there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000529/heroku-fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-faile

Comment: The Hobby paid plan doesnt give you more RAM (512 same as free), I have no experience with Vue, but if it is a memory leak I think the only way fwd is to find the cause. Maybe it is not a leak but just Heroku just needs to be provided with some initial configuration

Comment: yes, I know that there is no difference in RAM with free dyno there but I thought their support may help me)) that’s was the reason. I considered paid plan for my backend, not for FrontEnd (Vue). For know, development stage, free is quite enough for me. But I really appreciate your attempt to help me with my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have Docker images for your tasks you can easily deploy them to Digital Ocean's separate droplets.

That will cost you around 3 * $5 = $15 / monthly + $1 / month per droplet for backups.

[Here is](https://blog.machinebox.io/deploy-machine-box-in-digital-ocean-385265fbeafd) the flavor of how to deploy Docker containers to Digital Ocean's droplets.

The only downside is that you will needed Dockerized containers to setup infrastructure for yourself, and know how to do it.

My advice to you is if you have a lot to do and learn, stick with Heroku for a while. Once that get done you can go to setting up Linux/based VPS. There is a lot to learn and some situations can make you (as me previously) insane for some time.

Hope that helped.