# Heroku - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

Trying to deploy my app to Heroku (free Dyno) I keep getting an Error `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

I've already tried to set `node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100` as it's recommended in Heroku FAQ Support but it doesn't seem to help here.

My app runs well on my local Windows machine but on Heroku, the error pops up no matter what I do.

It crashes not on the stage of starting the script but on `tsc` compiling.

Maybe I've been using node options in a wrong place or something but I guess this approach doesn't work in my case for some reason.

Has anyone got into the same problem on Heroku and how did you solve it?

logging

```
2020-05-25T10:10:48.311880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run heroku`
2020-05-25T10:10:52.925897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:10:52.925919+00:00 app[web.1]: > express-backend@1.0.0 heroku /app
2020-05-25T10:10:52.925937+00:00 app[web.1]: > node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100&&npm-run-all clean compile copy start
2020-05-25T10:10:52.925938+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:10:54.329357+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:10:54.329371+00:00 app[web.1]: > express-backend@1.0.0 clean /app
2020-05-25T10:10:54.329372+00:00 app[web.1]: > rm -rf ./dist
2020-05-25T10:10:54.329372+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:10:55.482684+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:10:55.482694+00:00 app[web.1]: > express-backend@1.0.0 compile /app
2020-05-25T10:10:55.482695+00:00 app[web.1]: > tsc
2020-05-25T10:10:55.482695+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835222+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835249+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835250+00:00 app[web.1]: lu[70:0x44b09a0]    17193 ms: Mark-sweep 255.8 (257.3) -> 255.0 (257.6) MB, 260.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 3 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 278 ms) (average mu = 0.123, current mu = 0.062) allocation failure[70:0x44b09a0]    17326 ms: Mark-sweep 256.1 (257.6) -> 255.8 (257.6) MB, 83.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 25.2 ms in 12 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 133 ms) (average mu = 0.145, current mu = 0.185) allocation failur
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835251+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835252+00:00 app[web.1]: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835252+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835253+00:00 app[web.1]:     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13c5b79]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835253+00:00 app[web.1]: Security context: 0x01b71b3008d1 <JSObject>
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835255+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: addJSDocComment(aka addJSDocComment) [0xd947801e629] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:~15330] [pc=0x11ea5812c367](this=0x39366b7804b1 <undefined>,0x0ad037f13561 <Node map = 0xfdad2eb2b19>)
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835256+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: parseTypeMember(aka parseTypeMember) [0xd9478020029] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:~16687] [pc=0x11ea5818c740](this=0x39366b7804b1 <undefined>)...
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835432+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2020-05-25T10:11:13.835433+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.848262+00:00 app[web.1]: Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200525.101113.70.0.001.json
2020-05-25T10:11:13.848264+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js report completed
2020-05-25T10:11:13.848539+00:00 app[web.1]:  1: 0xa09830 node::Abort() [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.848757+00:00 app[web.1]:  2: 0xa09c55 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852130+00:00 app[web.1]:  3: 0xb7d71e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852131+00:00 app[web.1]:  4: 0xb7da99 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852132+00:00 app[web.1]:  5: 0xd2a1f5  [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852132+00:00 app[web.1]:  6: 0xd2a886 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852133+00:00 app[web.1]:  7: 0xd37105 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.852542+00:00 app[web.1]:  8: 0xd37fb5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.856595+00:00 app[web.1]:  9: 0xd3aa6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.856597+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd0163b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.856598+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x104300e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.856599+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0x13c5b79  [node]
2020-05-25T10:11:13.883615+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
2020-05-25T10:11:13.887422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-25T10:11:13.887588+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 134
2020-05-25T10:11:13.888930+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! express-backend@1.0.0 compile: `tsc`
2020-05-25T10:11:13.889100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 134
2020-05-25T10:11:13.889247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.889249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the express-backend@1.0.0 compile script.
2020-05-25T10:11:13.889411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-25T10:11:13.899422+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.900471+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-25T10:11:13.901218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-25T10_11_13_890Z-debug.log
2020-05-25T10:11:13.913416+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: "compile" exited with 134.
2020-05-25T10:11:13.919863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-25T10:11:13.920329+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-25T10:11:13.921443+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! express-backend@1.0.0 heroku: `node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100&&npm-run-all clean compile copy start`
2020-05-25T10:11:13.921603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-25T10:11:13.921779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.921933+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the express-backend@1.0.0 heroku script.
2020-05-25T10:11:13.922075+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-25T10:11:13.934678+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T10:11:13.935097+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-25T10:11:13.935307+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-25T10_11_13_922Z-debug.log
2020-05-25T10:11:14.015702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all -s clean",
    "predev": "npm-run-all -s clean",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "start": "node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 ./dist/server.js",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "copy": "cpy src/graphql/schemas/*.graphql dist/graphql/schemas --no-overwrite",
    "build": "tsc&&npm run copy",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm-run-all -s copy start\"",
    "heroku": "node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100&&npm-run-all clean compile copy start"
  },
  "config": {
    "node-options": "--optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.3",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.2",
    "@types/compression": "1.7.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "3.1.44",
    "@types/express": "4.17.3",
    "@types/graphql": "14.5.0",
    "@types/js-base64": "2.3.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "8.3.9",
    "@types/mongoose": "5.7.8",
    "@types/validator": "13.0.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "2.11.0",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "39.2.0",
    "graphql": "14.6.0",
    "graphql-middleware": "4.0.2",
    "graphql-shield": "7.2.3",
    "graphql-tools": "4.0.7",
    "js-base64": "2.5.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "merge-graphql-schemas": "1.7.6",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "5.9.6",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "password-validator": "5.0.3",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "simple-crypto-js": "2.2.0",
    "validator": "13.0.0",
    "winston": "3.2.1",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "cpy-cli": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web: npm run heroku
```

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I'm running into the exact same problem

Comment: @RichardRobinson, it was pretty long ago. I don’t already remember my solution in that project. But I remember I surfed internet and tried all possible ways to solve it and nothing helped me because of free limited on memory on Heroku. So, I guess I just changed hosting provider or upgraded it. Sorry, I don’t remember exactly  I should have posted it here

Comment: @RichardRobinson, were you ever able to solve this? I'm running into the exact same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem deploying angular app, I fixed it by adding node and npm versions in my `package.json` like:

`"engines": {"node": "12.x","npm": "6.x" }`

Comment: Have you tried adding NODE_OPTIONS  `--max_old_space_size=2560` (in config vars)  to increase memory limit ?

Comment: yep. I did. Heroku didn’t allow that for my free Account. It didn’t help

Comment: Hmm I also have free account, it was allowed for me. I don't have any other idea except if you also have additional error-R10 (boot timeout), you can try to add `"start": "ng serve --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"`,  also in your `package.json` (in "scripts")

Comment: I see now that you asked this question long time ago...anyways, maybe it helps someone :D

Comment: yes, it was very long time ago  so I don’t really remember how I solved that. But I clearly remember that it took a pretty long time  to solve it. Anyways thanks 

Answer (score 0):

You must compile the code before Heroku start to run their dynos. Compile them using `build`, or `postinstall` hooks

here's a simple example.

this one couple compile and run in the same line that Heroku starts to run dynos. (this won't work)

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.ts",
    "compile": "tsc"
    "heroku": "npm run compile && node build/app.js"
  }
```

this one compile will when heroku builds their thing and before start to run dynos.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.ts",
    "compile": "tsc"
    "heroku": "node build/app.js",
    "build": "npm run compile" 
  }
```

In this case, I separated your `clean`, `compile`, `copy` into `build`.

"scripts" section of packages.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all -s clean",
    "predev": "npm-run-all -s clean",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "start": "node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 ./dist/server.js",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "copy": "cpy src/graphql/schemas/*.graphql dist/graphql/schemas --no-overwrite",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile && npm run copy",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm-run-all -s copy start\"",
    "heroku": "npm start"
  }
```

more detail in [heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)